# How do i call google login dialog? (Attached screenshot)

Tags: authentication, google-signin

[image]

What name should I search for to find it?
Please tell me the keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Google One-tap sign-up. You can integrate using the API, follow this guide to setup Google One Tap into your website. After adding the Oauth2 ClientID in Google console. You can use it on your website as give,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="g_id_onload"
        data-client_id="XXXXXXXXXXXX-bk2lj5rs6l4c6g23nmtsfdh66qhfu921.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        data-login_uri="https://localhost:3000/login"
    >
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And you'll get the nice little credential picker dialog in your website.